# Drupal - Immediate email notifications that include CCK fields for multiple content types?

Tags: drupal, notifications, drupal-modules

I need email notifications for multiple content types, and for the content type's CCK fields to be included in the email. I also need the emails to be sent straight away, not on the next cron run.

The 2 main modules for email notifications are Notifications and Subscriptions. Subscriptions allows different messaging templates for different content types, but it cant send emails straight away. As I need emails to be sent very quickly (even 15 mins is too long), I would need to run my cron every 5 minuets or so. Even though this site is very low traffic, as im on shared hosting im guessing this isnt a good idea?

The Notifications module can send emails immediately. However you dont have different email templates for different content types. If I include the token for a CCK field not available in that content type, then the token text is sent in the email.

Any ideas on a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, just an idea for you to research.
Have you tried the Rules module?

Comment: Ill check it out. Email notifications when content is created should be easy enough, the only issue will be if I can send all the CCK fields in the email. Thanks

Comment: Email notification is supported on the core using Actions and Triggers. But I think you have a good chance of doing what you want with the Rules module

Comment: The issue that ive had with other notifications modules is that while its easy to send the node title and body in an email, accessing the CCK fields can be harder. Hopefully rules will do this though. Thanks

Comment: Ive basically got it working. The only issue left is that one of my CCK text fields allows for multiple entries and the email token from Rules only prints the first result. I guess this is a separate issue to my initial question so ill pursue it elsewhere unless someone knows the answer off the top of their heads. Thanks

Comment: Token Array module fixes that last problem   http://drupal.org/project/token_array